# Full width background with responsive height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

i'm trying to use Foundation to build an header with a full width image and a responsible height. There is some way to do this with CSS or I must use javascript? Could you help me?

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="page-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="background" data-interchange="[image/background.jpg, default],
          [image/small-background.jpg, small],
          [image/medium-background.jpg, medium],
          [image/large-background.jpg, large],
          [image/xlarge-background.jpg, xlarge]">
          <h1 class="text-center">
            <img data-interchange="[image/logo.png, (default)],
              [image/small-logo.png, (small)],
              [image/medium-logo.png, (medium)],
              [image/large-logo.png, (large)],
              [image/xlarge-logo.png, (xlarge)]" alt="Logo" />
            <noscript>
              <img src="image/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
            </noscript>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section id="page-content">
      <div id="services" class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
          <h2 class="text-center">Title</h2>
          <p>Text here</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

header#page-header {
  height: 100%;
}

header#page-header > div.row {
  height: 100%;
}

header#page-header div.background {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

header#page-header div.background > h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

app.js:

```
$(document).foundation();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into media queries and `background-size: cover`?

Comment: Yes, I already tested this property and it filled the entire div. That's fine, but my biggest problem is how to set its size by maintaining the aspect ratio to the width (100%) without the text below being positioned far from the background.

Answer (score 0):

rather than `height: 100%` try `auto`

```
header#page-header div.background {
  height: auto;  // may be this will work for you
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```